# android.media.MediaPlayer 2nd parameter

Tags: java, android

On the page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

**Example code off that page:**

Add the 2 following things:

1. `import android.R.raw;`
2. call to `getApplicationContext();`

---

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext();, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

**Question ?:** `R.raw.sound_file_1` parameter of `MediaPlayer.create` how do I define this as a file ie like `/dev/sda1/mediafile.xxx`

Thanks for any and all help in advance...Michael

Comment: What? I don't fully understand what you're asking. Let me try to answer tho, make a new folder called **raw** inside your **res** folder and put your sound file there. Is this the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a [`Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) as the second parameter. To create a `Uri` do the following:

```
Uri uri = Uri.create("/dev/sda1/mediafile.xxx")
```

Then pass it to your `MediaPlayer.create()` like so:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri)
```

Comment: This doesn't work; get error:Error:(32, 37) error: no suitable method found for create(Context,URI)
method MediaPlayer.create(Context,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to Uri)
method MediaPlayer.create(Context,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to int)

Comment: @user1984948, Sorry it is supposed to be `Uri` not `URI`. `URI` is for `Java.Net` not Android